# meaning of binding capacity and binding affinity

Tags: receptor

Actually, I am unfamiliar to biology, so when I read a thesis, the term "binding capacity" and "binding affinity" are really confusing.
Since my major is unrelated to biology, I don't know correct definition. Is there anyone who can explain differences between them clearly? Any references would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context would be useful, though there is nothing particularly special about the use of the words in this case. Binding affinity refers to how strongly two things bind (eg [a protein-ligand interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_(biochemistry))) and binding capacity refers to how much something can bind (eg [in reference to a chromatography column](http://geproteinskills.blogspot.ca/2014/10/resins-protein-binding-capacities.html)).

Comment: references are really helpful, the key is "how much" and "how strong". right? you resolved my confusion

Comment: @victoria Yes, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context... is hard to give a detailed answer.

I understand for bindind capacity the ability of a molecule to bind or attach to another molecule.
Binding affinity is the strength of the binding interaction between a single molecule and the other one.

Comment: oh l am sorry, since I am not familar to biology, I thought that the terms are often used in biology, so the only reason for confusing me is lack of my knowledge. So, I didn't add some context, but material I found is just about receptor's binding ability and affinity.